# Не работает запрос INSERT на python с pymysql

Tags: c#, python, sql, insert, pymysql

Использую библиотеку `pymysql`, `python` версии 3.7.9. Вот код подключения к базе и добавления записи:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='',
                                 user='',
                                 password='',
                                 db='',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = f"INSERT INTO Users (user_name) VALUES (\"Test\")"
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

К базе данных подключается успешно, запрос не выдаёт ошибки, но запись не добавляется. В чём может быть проблема? Данные БД правильные, подключение я проверяла. Я выполняю этот же запрос в phpMyAdmin и он срабатывает, также тестировала такой же запрос на c# через библиотеку `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`:

```
                MySqlConnection connection = null;

                try
                {
                    string connStr = "";
                    connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Ошибка подключения к БД: {ex.Message}", "Ошибка",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                try
                {
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO Users (user_name) VALUES (\"Test\")";
                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
                    command.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Ошибка: {ex.Message}", "Ошибка",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Error); ;
                }
```

Этот код на `c#` срабатывает, хотя запрос идентичный, я копировала и данные с БД, и сам запрос с кода на `c#` в код на `python`, так что в этом не может проблемы. Я не могу понять в чём проблема...

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строчку `"INSERT INTO Users (user_name) VALUES (\"Test\")"`      
на `"INSERT INTO Users(user_name) VALUES(?)"`        
но тогда замените вторую строчку на `cursor.execute(sql,(Test))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pymysql.cursors

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='your_username',
                             password='your_passwordd',
                             database='your_database_name',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO Users (user_name) VALUES (%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('Test'))
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: спасибо, `with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "INSERT INTO Users (user_name) VALUES (%s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('Test'))
    connection.commit()` вот такой код сработал, а зачем `with connection:`, у меня с этой строчкой получалась ошибка `__enter__`